# SweetAlert small on mobile devices, and Resize SweetAlert icons

Tags: javascript, html, css, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I am linking to this SweetAlert library `https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js`, and when I display an alert on mobile, it displays very small. I have increased the text size, but the success, error, warning animations are very small. How can I resize these animations, or make the alert mobile friendly?

This is without CSS
[image: Without Css]

[image: With CSS]

And with CSS

Comment: The answer above works BUT! since you use swal2-popup / font-size property
have in mind that the alerts that have text on it like "warning or info" will change size too

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the same thing....

2 options:
Add this in CSS:

```
.swal2-popup {
font-size: 2rem;
}
```

or

Use these links for your cdn... and it will work....(but its sweet alert1)

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert-dev.js

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.css

Answer (score 5):

I got the same problem, because i forgot to include meta viewport tag...

try inserting this into `head` of your page

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are links for CDN for SweetAlert2:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@7.12.15/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>

<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@7.12.15/dist/sweetalert2.min.css'>
```

I got these links from [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-pretty-popup-messages-using-sweetalert2--cms-30662) .